# Fatigue logic on UI components

Tags: tooltips

I'm working on an app, and one of the things being built is a tooltip dialogue to present to the user, which is dismissible. However, I'm having trouble coming up with a way to create an enjoyable UX and not annoy users, but still prompt them multiple times with this tooltip dialogue.

I think the approach I'm going to take is to show the user the tooltip dialogue N times with a minimum of M time between each tooltip presentation, but I don't know what the correct values are for M and N, or even if this is the right approach at all. Hoping someone here has some experience dealing with things like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As with everything in UX, the answer is "it depends."

Your question is a bit vague, with many possible interpretations. I can offer you a generic answer. To get a more detailed reply, you could also amend your question to include details and specific examples.

You're developing an app. I assume this means for a smart phone or tablet. If this is what you're doing, then all the major platforms have style guides that provide you with acceptable answers to this question.

- https://www.google.com/design/
- http://developer.blackberry.com/design/bb10/
- https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/
- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160204060724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/africaapps/archive/2014/03/08/ux-guidelines-for-windows-phone-8.aspx)

Many of the basics are the same across platforms, so if one style guide doesn't have the answer you need, try another.